# Can we change the value of alpha(learning rate ) dynamically to achieve minima early?(liner regression )

Tags: regression

I am new to machine learning .In linear regression we use alpha as a constant (which is learning rate ) .We take alpha such as learning is fastest . Can we do like this make alpha large when we away from minima and make it small when we are near minima . Do you this this approach would work fine or name or please tell me where am i wrong

Comment: could you please add tags machine-learning and gradient-descent, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, learning rates that decrease with time are common.  For example,
the [SGDRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html)
in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org)
uses learning rate
$eta = { eta_0 \over t^{0.25} } $; 
see the [implementation details](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#implementation-details) .

(Learning rates can also be different for each feature / component
instead of the same for all;
and can also be adaptive.
Different problems  $\Rightarrow$ many recipes for learning rates
—
more recipes than online test cases.)